# How to load content of other html to div without losing css style?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I tried to load other html content to my div but I found that I lose the style of the loaded content.

I tried using some of below code:

**.load()**:

```
$('#paymentsExecutiveExSum').load("summary/ExecutiveSummary/paymentsExecutiveSummary.html");
```

**.get() & .append()**;

```
$.get("summary/ExecutiveSummary/paymentsExecutiveSummary.html",function(data){
    $("#paymentsExecutiveExSum").append(data);
});
```

I use the same code:

```
<a data-role="button" class="fullWidth">Test</a>
```

My css from **Inspect Element**:

**Loaded** (from other html using normal way to load html)

[image: Loaded]

**Not loaded** (my case, basically it doesn't load the JQM button's css)

[image: Not loaded]

**UPDATE:**

Here is my full code:

**home.html**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/my.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme-addon.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.css"/>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script>
        var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
        var animation = "none";

        Number.prototype.formatMoney = function(c, d, t){
            var n = this, 
                c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c, 
                d = d == undefined ? "." : d, 
                t = t == undefined ? "," : t, 
                s = n < 0 ? "-" : "", 
                i = parseInt(n = Math.abs(+n || 0).toFixed(c)) + "", 
                j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
            return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "");
        };
    </script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

</head>
<body onload="WL.Client.init({})" id="content" style='display: none' class="fullWidth">

    <div data-role="page" id="homePage">
        <div data-role="content">
            <a href="#" data-role="button" id="login" class="fullWidth">Log In</a>
        <script src="js/my.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </div>

    <script src="js/plugin/simplesplitview-1.0.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messages.js"></script>

</body>
```

**my.js**

```
$('#login').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    jq.mobile.changePage("next.html", { transition: animation, changeHash: true });
});
```

Then, when it comes to **summary.html**:

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <button class="back" data-theme="a">Back</button>
    <div class="ui-title headerTitle">Summary</div>
</div>

<div data-role="content" id='splitviewcontainer' class='splitviewcontainer summary'>

    <div class='leftside'>
        <div id="executiveSummaryMenuGroupButton">
            <a id="paymentsExecutiveSummaryButton" data-role="button" class="executiveSummaryTitleMenuButton">Payments</a>
            <div class="horizontalDivider"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='rightside' id='paymentsExSum'></div>    
</div>

<script src="js/summary.js"></script>
```

**summary.js**

```
$(function(){
    $('#executiveSummaryMenuGroupButton').hide();
    $('#splitviewcontainer').simplesplitview();
});

$('#paymentsExecutiveSummaryButton').click(function(e){
    $("#paymentsExSum").load("summary/ExecutiveSummary/paymentsExecutiveSummary.html").trigger('create'); //It seems it doesn't work
    $('#splitviewcontainer').simplesplitview('showRight', 'paymentsExSum', true);
});
```

What is the proper way to load other html's content to div without losing css style?

Comment: Make sure your class names are not deeply nested

Comment: Can you please explain more?

Comment: If your HTML structure is `<div class="a"> <div class="b"> </div></div>` for example and if you have the styles like `.a .b { somestyle  }` .. If you move out `div.b` and inject some where else, obviously the styles won't be applied case according the current CSS styles are only applied to b when nested inside a

Comment: hi Sushanth, thx for the explanation, actually the JQM's css that's not loaded not mine.. Pls see my edited post.

Answer (score 6):

### Explanation:

Your first need to load them then manually trigger page enhancement. You are not loosing style, you don't have it in the first place. jQuery Mobile enhances content during the page initialization, every dynamically added content must be enhanced manually, read more about it [**here**](http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/).

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
    $("#index").load("load.html", function() {
        $(this).trigger("pagecreate");
    });
});
```

All you need is **`trigger("pagecreate");`** which will enhance page markup to the correct jQuery Mobile look. If you are only appending to the content DIV then use **`trigger('create');`** but this time on content DIV.

### Working example:

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>    
        <script>
            $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
                $("#index").load("load.html", function() {
                    $(this).trigger("pagecreate");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="index">

        </div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

#### load.html

```
<div data-theme="b" data-role="header">
    <h1>Index page</h1>
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn-active">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /navbar -->  
</div>

<div data-role="content">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn-active">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /navbar -->  
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work in me too :( it's very strange. I'll post more code later.

Comment: When you are talking about styles are you talking about classic jQuery Mobile styles or your own custom styles?

Comment: Let me check and come back to you very soon

Comment: Can you also add your HTML, they I can create you an example? My example is working, I don't know if you have tried that or even looked at a link I posted. You need to understand that it is not enough to just load HTML, if you have any jQuery Mobile content it needs to be enhanced with methods I mentioned in my answer. In case you are loading content (not related to jQUery Mobile) its css must be initialized before you load your content.

Comment: Sorry forgot to post my code. I will post it around 3 hours from now. Btw I tested your code by triggering the pagecreate again, however, I'm using another plugin using worklight and as far as I tested, the pagecreate, pageshow, and its friends never called.

Comment: I will be here next few hours so I will give you an answer as soon as you post your code. Also if it is not a problem you can mail me your project and I will fix it for you.

Comment: Hi Gajotres, sorry I didn't any chance to update it yesterday. Pls see my edited question :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use both of them,but

```
$('#paymentsExecutiveExSum').load("summary/ExecutiveSummary/paymentsExecutiveSummary.html");
```

will replace all the previous html with the new one and

```
$.get("summary/ExecutiveSummary/paymentsExecutiveSummary.html",function(data){
    $("#paymentsExecutiveExSum").append(data);
});
```

will append the new data to the previous html,but not remove the old one..You can also use .html like

```
$.get("summary/ExecutiveSummary/paymentsExecutiveSummary.html",function(data){
    $("#paymentsExecutiveExSum").html(data);
});
```

That will replace the old data with the new data

Comment: All of them still lose the style :(

Comment: @Rendy for the newly created html there may be parents are different,So need to consider the new classes and parents and also you need to include css file at the paymentsExecutiveSummary.html also

Comment: Only wonder, is it a good practice to put css on an html and not in the top html(home.html for example) ?

Comment: Look he is loading the html data from another page so that he need to include css at that page also....while loading itself the css in main page doent apply the css